# Illustrator PDF save as: File size differs from yesterday to today in 1MB.?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, file-size

I am saving a file (rich in text and photos, 15 artboards) as a PDF. I finished it yesterday and exported it. Got a 4.9 MB file. Fine. This morning I noticed a Typo. Corrected it (Changed no photo, nothing, only corrected the typo) and saved as to PDF again (Using the exact same settings. They are a preset I have been using for years, so no possibility of error, plus I have doubled check). The file I get is 5.9MB. That is 1 MB more (20%+more!). Why could this be happening? Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you open the .pdf and save as .pdf or open the original .ai and save as .pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for bloated PDFs from Illustrator is when the "keep editable in Illustrator" option is active. When this option is on, it embeds the whole .ai file (compressed, for sure) in the PDF.

You may also have a look at the font embedding options, and, as mentioned in an other answer, the image compression settings.

If that does not quite help, a little Voodoo helps, by closing the edited Illustrator file, maybe even restart Illustrator, reopening it and export again; I had that in a recent case where the normal export is around 110 kB, but once, it was 1.4 MB… and that trick did help.